# Which Certifications is more demanding for QA, and Software Testing professionals?

Tags: certification

Which Certification Is demanding for Senior SQA Engineers?

- ISTQB
- CSTE
- CSTP
- CTM

I am planning for QA certification but don't know which one is best.Please suggest me..

Comment: By "demanding" do you mean "is in the most demand" by companies hiring Senior SQA Engineers?

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. Yes by demanding I mean-"the most demand by companies hiring SQA Engineers."

Answer (score 2):

Greatly depends on the location you are in the world. I have the feeling [ISTQB](http://www.istqb.org/) is the certification that is most respected worldwide.

Here in the Netherlands [ISTQB](http://www.istqb.org/) and [TMap Next](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Management_Approach) are the two popular certifications.
I can only guess that in other parts of the world this could be totally different.

The only way to determine what qualification is in demand for seniors is too count the number of times a certification shows up in recent job descriptions and maybe count the certifications Senior SQA engineers have on their LinkedIn profiles.

Personally I think work experience is far more important for a senior than any certification, certifications are just to prove you have a certain basic level and can communicate with others in the industry.

Answer (score 2):

To determine if any certification is an aid to gaining employment, here's a method I used in the past, that you could use too:

http://www.allthingsquality.com/2010/04/software-qa-certifications-aid-to.html

- Go to a jobs website (like Monster.com)
- Search for "Software QA"
- Note the number of jobs returned
- Add a search term for the certification of interest like "Software QA CSTE"
- Compare the results you get to the prior results
- Repeat for the other certifications of interest
- Compare all the results

My conclusion at the time - at least in my part of the world, certifications matter very little, if at all.